# Is there another way than :hover to change font color

Tags: css

I would like to give specific color font when I mouse over.

```
<div className="actions" className="icon"><div><span></span><a href={url_path} target="_blank">trailer</a></div></div>
```

I tried but didn't work. Is there another way than :hover??

```
.icon:hover , .actions:hover{
  color : #FF382E;
}
.actions{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.icon{
      float: right;
      width: 50px;
      height: 14px;
      padding: 30px 0 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #93939c;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need two `className` attributes on the same element, rather than a single `class` attribute?

Comment: in addition to the className issue, you needt to be more specific and target the `a` element and not the parent one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hover part is fine, the only problem is that `:hover` targets the element being hovered by default. You can adapt your css to target the element more specifically:

```css
.icon:hover , .actions:hover div a{
  color : #FF382E;
}
.actions{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
.icon{
      float: right;
      width: 50px;
      height: 14px;
      padding: 30px 0 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #93939c;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions" class="icon">
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <a href={url_path} target="_blank">trailer</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Done some changes and updated your code.

```css
.icon:hover a {
  color: #FF382E;
}

.actions {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #93939c;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions icon">
  <div><span></span><a href={url_path} target="_blank">trailer</a></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsxkc6gu/3/)